# How to make class usable in different HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I have a **class Attribute** which has 2 variables  say **int a,b**;

I want to use class Attribute in two different HashSet.

The **first hash set** considers objects as equal when the value of **a** is same.
But the **second hash set** considers objects as equal when the value of **b** is same.

I know if I **override** the **equals** method the hashset will use the overriden version of equals to compare two objects but in this case I would need two different implementations of  equals()

**One way** is to **create** two **subclasses** of attribute and provide them with different equals method but I want to know if there is a better way to do it such that I dont have to create subclass of Attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem kind of doesn't make sense. Your objects are the same if `a` is the same, but not. Then if `b` is the same the objects are the same, but they're also not. Make two classes, please, because they're different classes with different purposes.

Comment: @Andre I think it kind of does make sense... Equality semantics could be considered inherent to a class, but then so could comparison. Yet you can provide custom Comparators in some collections methods. Allowing only a single criterium for equality to be defined in a class may be the "pure" approach, but I think giving a developer freedom and flexibility is more important than adhering to very strict concepts. Think about it... why are Ruby and Scala gaining traction while Java has always faced much criticism?

Comment: Custom comparators were built and implemented for an entirely different purpose that what you're describing. Two objects are the same if their `equals()` method returns true, no matter what context you're calling the method from.

Comment: @Andre Yes, and that does completely make sense from a strict point of view. But the thing is, being strict doesn't always help developers. It does for those who can't be trusted to know a hash code from a memory address, but constraints end up being frustrating for those who just want agility. It's opinion though. But I'm beginning to feel that Java was created for that "not-so-disciplined" class of devs and it's slowly starting to get on my tits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some thing different, **Instead** of using the **HashSet**, I have **used**  **HashMap** where I have used **int a**  as a key in first HashMap and the object is stored as value. 
And in the other **HashMap** I have kept the key as **int b** and the object as value.

This provides me a way to Hash on both the variables **a** and **b** so I dont have to make any sub classes.

And also, I get O(1) time instead of O(log n). But I know I am paying the price by using some more memory but my main concern was time so I chose HashMap over TreeSet.

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to not use `HashSet`, but use `TreeSet` instead. It's the same `Set` interface, but there is a `TreeSet` constructor that lets you pass in a `Comparator`. That way you could leave the `Attribute` class unchanged- just create two different comparators and use it like

```
Set<Attribute> setA = new TreeSet<Attribute>(comparatorForA);
Set<Attribute> setB = new TreeSet<Attribute>(comparatorForB);
```

The comparator takes care of the equality check (e.g. if `compare` returns 0, the objects are equal)

Comment: That's just gonna have effect on ordering, though. It still wouldn't allow entries that are equal according to `equals`.

Comment: You lose the speed of using a hashing algorithm, but it'll work.

Comment: @G_H - The comparator returns 0 when both fields are equal which means the objects should be considered equal themselves. For example, if `a` is an `int` you have `int compare(Object x, Object y) { return x.a - y.a; }`

Comment: @DavidHarkness Just checked the JavaDoc for TreeSet again... You're right, it doesn't use equals, only compareTo. Then this would be the best solution. Sorry for the downvote, I can't reverse it unless the answer gets edited. Too hasty :(

Comment: Whoop, now I can! +1. Still a bit shocked that they so gleefully violate the contract for `Set` after implementing that interface...

Comment: @G_H: I thought of comparator but the data I have is huge and I really don't want it to sort unnecessarily because I really don't care about ordering. so ruled out the option of using TreeSet .. thanks for ur comment though !!

Comment: @amitmodi The basic operation performance is O(log(n)). That would probably still be acceptable. Not the (usual) O(1) you could get from using hash values, but you can do a lot worse.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no "Equalizer" class that can override the `equals` logic. There is such a thing for sorting, where you can either use natural sorting based on the `Comparable` implementation or provide your own `Comparator`. I've actually wondered why there's no such thing for equality checks.

Since the semantics of equality are defined by a class and could be considered a trait of that class, the two subclasses approach seems the most natural. Maybe someone knows a useful pattern for doing this in a more simple manner, but I've never encountered it.

EDIT: just thought of something... you could use two `Map` instances, like `HashMap`, with the first one using `a` as key and the second using `b` as key. It'd let you detect collisions. You could then simply link the attribute to the associated instance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to modify `HashMap` and `HashSet` to accept hashing and equality-testing strategies.

```
public interface Hasher {
    int hashCode(Object o);
}

public interface Equalizer {
    int areEqual(Object o1, Object o2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to bypass `HashSet` and use `HashMap` directly. For the first, store each `Attribute` using its `a` property as the key, and for the other use `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a bit hacky but lesser effort solution :)
Swap the values of a and b when storing in second hashset so that uniqueness is defined by value of b and then when reading the class from hashset then swap the value of a and b again to retain the original state. So the same equals/hascode methods will serve the purpose.